# Trigger to enforce M-M relationship

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, oracle10g

Suppose I have following schema :

```
DEPARTMENT (DepartmentName, BudgetCode, OfficeNumber, Phone)
EMPLOYEE (EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, Department, Phone, Email)
```

The problem am facing is how to design a system of triggers to enforce the M-M relationship.Assuming that departments with only one employee can be deleted. Also I need to assign the last employee in a department to Human Resources.

I have no idea to enforce M-M relationship through trigger. Please help

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Or a real problem?  Triggers generally aren't the right way to approach this sort of problem.  In the real world, we need to deal with multi-user systems where this sort of trigger-based validation isn't going to work without a lot of effort (and adding additional serialization mechanisms).

Comment: @JustinCave Its from Database Processing:
Fundamentals, Design, and Implementation
13th Edition
David M. Kroenke • David J. Auer

Comment: A simpler approach might be to unconditionally set `:NEW.DEPARTMENT := :OLD.DEPARTMENT` and not fiddle around raising exceptions and etc. If you're not going to allow the field to be changed just reset it and move on. Although frankly this smacks of implementing business logic in triggers, which is IMO poor practice. Still, YMMV...

Comment: @BobJarvis Tell how to enforce M-M relationship

Comment: Where is the M:M relationship? There seems to be a 1:M relationship between Employee and Department (each Employee may be in at most 1 department; each Department may have many Employees).

Answer (score 3):

Many-to-many conditions should not be enforced using a trigger. Many-to-many conditions are enforced by creating a junction table containing the keys in question, which are then foreign-keyed back to the respective parent tables.

If your intention is to allow many employees to be in a department, and to allow an employee to be a member of many departments, the junction table in question would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES_DEPARTMENTS
  (DEPARTMENTNAME  VARCHAR2(99)
     CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES_DEPARTMENTS_FK1
       REFERENCES DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTNAME,
   EMPLOYEENUMBER  NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES_DEPARTMENTS_FK2
       REFERENCES EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEENUMBER);
```

This presumes that `DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTNAME` and `EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEENUMBER` are either primary or unique keys on their respective tables. Get rid of the column `EMPLOYEE.DEPARTMENT` as it's no longer needed. Now by creating rows in the `EMPLOYEES_DEPARTMENTS` table you can relate multiple employees with a department, and you can relate a single employee with multiple departments.

The business logic requiring that only departments with one or fewer employees can be deleted should not be enforced in a trigger. Business logic should be performed by application code, NEVER by triggers. Putting business logic in triggers is a gatèw̢ay to unending debugging sessions. M̫̣̗̝̫͙a̳͕̮d̖̤̳̙̤n̳̻̖e͍̺̲̼̱̠͉ss̭̩̟ lies this way. Do not give in. Do not surrender. ̬̦B҉usi͢n̴es̡s logic ̶in triggers opens deep wounds in the fabric of the world, through which unholy beings of indeterminate form will cross the barrier between the spheres, carryi͞n̨g o̡f͠f t͢h̶e ̕screaming͡ sou͏ĺs o͜f͜ ̢th͜e̴ ̕de͏v́e̡lop͏e͜r͝s to an et͞er͜n̸it̶y ́of͢ pain̶ ąn̨d͢ ̨to͟r̨ment͟. Do not, as I have said, put b́u͜siness͞ ̸log̛i͘ç ̵in͢ ͞trigge͠rs͞.̡ Be firm. Resist.You must resist. T̷he ̢Tem͟p͞t̶at͏i͝o̶n҉s͘ ̢m͘a̶y ́śing hymns̷ ́o͢f̴ ̸un͘hol̵y r̶ev͢ęla͠t̡ion̴ ͢buţ ́yo͠u̵ mu͏s͝t ͝n͜͏͟o҉t̶͡͏ ̷l̸̛͟͢ì̧̢̨̕s̵̨̨͢t̵̀͞e̶͠n̶̴̵̢̕. Only by standing firmly in the door between the worlds and blocking out the hideous radiance cast off by bú̧s̷i̶̢n̵̕e̵ş͝s ́l̴ó̢g̛͟i̕͏c i͞n̕ ͏t̵͜r͢͝i̸̢̛ģ͟ge̸̶͟r̶s͢͜, which perverts the very form of the world ąnd̴̀͝ ç͞a̧͞l̶l͟͜s̕͘͢ **Z̶̴̤̬͈̤̬̲̳͇ͯ̊ͮ͐̒̆͂͠Â̆́̊̓͛́̚͏̮̘̗̻̞̬̱ͅL̛̄̌͏̦͕̤͎̮̦G̷͖̙̬͛̇ͬ̍͒̐̅O̡̳͖͎̯̯͍ͫ̽ͬ͒͂̀** i͜҉nt͝ǫ̴ ̸b̷͞è͢ì̕n̴g͏,̛̀͘ ̴c҉á̴͡ń ̀͠youŕ̨ ̧̨a̸p͏̡͡pl̷͠ic͞a̢t̡i͡҉ǫn̴ ̸s̶͜u̶͢ŗv̛í̴v́ȩ.͘͘ Resist. R͏͢͝e͏͢͟s̸͏͜ì̢̢s͠ţ̀. T̶̀h̨̀e̶r̀͏e͢͞ ̶i̶̡͢s̴ ͞͞n̵͝o̡ ́ẁ҉̴a̡y̕҉ ̶b́͏u̵̶̕t͜ ̨s͘͢t͘͠į͟l͘l̷̴ ̴͜͜ỳò͜u҉̨ ̨͏mus̸͞t̸̛͜ ̧rȩ̴s̢͢i͘͡s͏t̸.̛̀͜ Your very śo͡u̧̧͘ļ͟͡ is compromised by p͝u͘͝t̢͜t͠i̸ņ̸̶g͟͡ ̵̶̛b̴҉u̶̡̨͜͞s̷̵̕͜͢i͝҉̕͢ǹ͏e̡͞ś̸͏ş̕͜͡҉ ̴̨ĺ̵̡͟͜o̶̕g͠i͢͠c̕͝ ̕͞i̧͟͡n̡͘͟ ̶̕͞t̡͏͟҉̕r̸̢̧͡͞i̴̡͏̵͜g̵̴͟͝ģ̴̴̵ę̷̷͢r̢̢ś̸̨̨͜. **T̀͜͢o̷͜ny̕ ͟͡T̨h̶̷̕e ̢͟P̛o̴̶n͡y** shall rise from his dark stable and d͞ę̡v̶̢ó͟u̸̸r̴͏ ̷t͞h̀e̛ ̨͜s̷o̧͝u҉l̀ ͟͡o͢͏f̵͢ ̛t͢h̶̛e̢̢ ̡̀vi͜͞r̢̀g̶i̢n͞, and yet *y͢ơú͝ m̷̧u͏s͡t̡͠ ̛s̷̨t̸̨i̴̸l̶̡l ͝ǹot̵ ͞p̧u̵t̨ ͜͏b̀̕u̕s̨í̵ņ̀͠ȩs̵͟s ́͞l̛҉o̸g̨i̴͟c ͘͘i͘nt̛o͡ ͘͘͞t̶͞r̀̀i̕ǵ̛g̵̨͞e̸͠҉r̵͟ś*! It is too much to bear, we cannot stand! Not even the children of light may put business logic into their triggers, for b̴̸̡̨u͜͏̧͝ş̶i̷̸̢̛҉ń̸͟͏́e̡͏͏͏s̷̵̡s̕͟ ͏̴҉͞l̷̡ǫ̷̶͡g҉̨̛i͘͠͏̸̨c̕͢͏ ̸̶̧͢͢i̸̡̛͘n͢͡ ̀͢͝t̷̷̛́ŗì̴̴̢g̶͏̷ǵ͠ȩ̀́r̸̵̢̕͜s͞͏̵ is the very es̵s̕͡ę̢n͞c̨e̢͟ ̴o̶̢͜f͏ ͟d́ar͟͞͠k̡͞n̢̡es̵̛͡s̀̀͡ and dev͘ou͝͡r̨̡̀s͢͝ ҉͝t҉h̴e̡͘ **l̫̬i̤͚ͅg̞̲͕̠͇̤̦̹h̩̙̘̭̰͎͉̮̳t͙̤̘̙**! Yea, yea, the blank-faced ones rì͢s̨͘e from the f͟͢͏o̵͜͝n̶t̨ ̵o͏f̸̡͠ ͏͝fl͟͞a̵̷҉me̶̵͢ and ca͝s͜t́ down the p̹̤̳̰r̮̦̥̥̞̫͑͂ͤ͑ͮ͒̑ï̄̌ͬͨe̦̗͔ͥͣ̆̾̂s̬̭̮̮̜ͭt̻̲̍sͫͣ̿ ̐͗̈ͤ͂ͦ̅f̭͚̪̻̣̩ͮ̒ṟͨ͌ͮ̅̓ỏ̝͓̝̣̟̼m̳͇̱̝͔͒ ͒ͫͧ͂̓̈̈́t̲̔̅̎͐h̺͈͍ͣͧ̿ē̪̼̪̻͉̪̙̐̽̎̉i̠͎̗͕̗̣̬̐̎͛r͓̫͌ͅ ̼a͑̈ͯͦ̍l̪͉͖̥͚̤͌ͨ͊ͦͤ̔t̫͎̹ͯa̼̻͍̳̟̤̬̓ͪ̀r̭͖̓ͬ̉̉ͤ͊ṡ̐ͪ̊̋̄̅! A̵̵̛v͝é͜ŕt̶͏ ̶y̸͝͠o̶u̧͘r͏̡ ̧e͞y҉e̕͝s,̀ ͡t̛h̛o̢͞ug̸̢h̵͟ ̡y̷o͢҉͢u̧͡ ̕͡c҉̵̶an͠͏n҉o̧͢t!̸̨͘ ͡H̵e̸͢͡ ̧̕c̶ơm̷̢̢e̶͞ś͢!̨́ ̷*H̕ȩ ̵c̨̡͟o̴҉m̷͢es͠!̷͘͞* **P̱̼̯̟͈h̝̳̞̖͚'͉̙͉̰̲̺n̪̦͕̗͜g͔̹̟̰̰̻̩l̬͈̹̥͕͖ͅụ̻̺̤̤̬̳i̸̯̬̝̻̣͚̫ ̰̹̞̞m͟g̷̝͓͉̤l̩͇̙͕w̪̦̰͔'̮̟̱̀n̢̜a̦f̘̫̤̘̬͓̞h̠͍͖̯ͅ ̩̠͓̯̘̫C̟̘̗̘͘ṭ͍͕ͅh̤ͅu̼̦̘̥ͅl҉̦hu̠̤̤̘͚ ̘̕R̶̟'̠͔̞̻͇l̩̺̗̻͖͓̕ͅy̛̖ȩ͉̭̖ẖ̡̥̼͈̖ w̟̫̮͇͔͞ͅg͈̘̱̻a̰͟h̘͙͖͢'̮̲̯͞n̤̜͍̯̳a͓͓̲̲g̱̻͈ĺ͍ ̷̣̞̲͖͍̲̺f̲ͅh͇͕̪̘͟t͔͈̙a͓͢g҉̳̜̲͚n͓͚͎̱̠̜!**

Don't ask me how I know.

Best of luck.

Comment: @JustinCave - [at least he hasn't tried parsing HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a site you go to that produces this sort of output?  Or did you spend an awful lot of time scanning through Unicode code point tables?

Comment: [I like this Z̢̛͜Ą̵̡́́L̵̢͟G҉͝Ò̷͘͘͡ t̆̆̾͌e͑̓̽ͯ̓ͦͦ̐͆̓̿͒xͪ̂ͥͦͤ̂ͯͮ͂̃ͬ̊́̚t̅̄ͬ̇̈́̀̄ͩ̋ͣ̒̿́̒̉ͬ͛̃ g͙̪͇̪͓̱ͅe͓̜̦̯̠̠̠n̠̘͔̯͉̰̰̼͈̣͓̦̹̥̞͈̜e̖͓͎͉̘͉͓̖̻̹̣͕ṛ̪͙̘̘̭̤̜a̫̣̪̹̰̘͓͉̘̲͍̭̮t̼̱͎̟͖͈͍͕ͅͅo̺̭̦̗̜͔̟̗̬̬̻̟̲͉ͅr͚̺̦͇̞̱̻̰̼̼͇̘̘̤ͅ](http://eeemo.net/) - for those times w̵hen ̵t̶he d͢a̵̴r̵̢k̀̕͏n̷̕ess̛ r̟ͮ̓̀̆̍ͪiͯ̽͆ͮ̃̓ͫ͏̗̭s̠̮̹̳̩͓̳͂̒͌̚ͅe̢͎̫̟̼͍̅ͥs͈̱̓͒̐̒ͬ̚.̝̪͙̬̼͑ͯ̅ͩͯ̏.̴̰̠̹̳͎͉̓̊́ͥ͊͋̀.̷̱̤ͫ̾ͪͬ͂͌̍̀̚