# How to look at the table whose insertion fired the trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table of bids and everytime a bid is added in an auction I want to create new notifications to every bidder in that auction. As this is for a class of databases I though of doing a trigger to show some skills in oracle pl/sql. 
My trigger is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_notifs
AFTER INSERT ON bid
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO notification(id_notif, id_auction, username, time, seen_state)
  SELECT notif_id_seq.NEXTVAL, :NEW.id_auction, username, SYSDATE, 0
  FROM bid
  WHERE bid.id_auction = :NEW.id_leilao;
END;
/
```

**Now this trigger won't work because it's accessing the table that fired it**. It is not a problem though because **I'm not changing it** and it really needs to be after the insertion because I need to see if it passes the constraints. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a SELECT from the table on which a row trigger is declared or you get the dreaded "mutating table" error, but it doesn't look to me like you need to SELECT anything. Try rewriting your trigger as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_notifs
  AFTER INSERT ON bid
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO notification
    (id_notif, id_auction, username, time, seen_state)
  VALUES
    (notif_id_seq.NEXTVAL, :NEW.id_auction, username, SYSDATE, 0);
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: But I need the usernames that are associated to the auction through the bid table.

Comment: Then the right thing to do is to find the username in your program logic and put the correct username in when doing the INSERT. This smacks of putting [business logic in a trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998789/trigger-to-enforce-m-m-relationship), which is a bad idea anyways.

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer Use **USER** to get user name of connected session