# I don’t want field for a specific row to not be updated atall

Tags: java, sql, oracle, triggers

I have a table named users in which there is accountlocked field ... the possible values of that field are Y and N ... if the user from frontend logs in with 3attempts of wrong password then accountlocked will be Y which means account is locked... but I have a specific user that I don’t want the accountlocked to be updated to Y... I created a trigger which can update it to N once it is Y... but I just don’t want the field to be updated to Y atall in the first for that specific user

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER traccountunlock AFTER
   UPDATE OF accountlocked ON users
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (new.username=‘Testuser ’)
BEGIN
    IF :new.accountlocked = 'Y' THEN
        UPDATE users
        SET
            accountlocked = 'N'
        WHERE
            username IN (
                'Testuser'
            );

    END IF;
END;
```

This works but it does it after the field is updated to Y,but I don’t want it to update to Y at the first place something like instead of ... but instead of works only for views not tables in oracle

Note: I can do it through java code but, I’m not looking for that solution as it needs deploy and future issues

Comment: This should be more conviently handled in your application.

Comment: Yes, We know that but we are looking for something through SQL for various reasons. Thanks for looking into this

Comment: Like @GMB said you could easily solve your problem in your application. Could you explain why you dont want to do this? I see you dont want becasue of deployment and future issues but could you be a bit more specific

Comment: There are 2 reasons for this .  

1.I dont want to hardcode some test users in the prod code
2. If the testing team needs it for a new user or stuff like that we again need to push those changes and deploy it along the sprint process and that again needs a lot of tracking and stuff thats expensive, so looking to decouple this with the help of a trigger or somehting as such from SQL DB @Collin

Comment: [You might want to consider this post before you implement bu͞sin͠es̴ś ̶l͡og̨ic̷ in a t҉̸r̷͏i̶̵ģ̷̡g̡e͘҉r͞҉](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32009988/213136)

Answer (score 2):

It would be this one. However, I think you should solve it better on application level.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER traccountunlock 
   BEFORE UPDATE OF accountlocked ON users
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (new.username = 'Testuser')
BEGIN
    IF :new.accountlocked = 'Y' THEN
        :new.accountlocked := 'N';
    END IF;
END;
```

--Just Updated with the working version

Comment: Tried this but getting an error 
Error(2,28): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; indicator @Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: You need a semicolon after `:new.accountlocked = 'N'`

Comment: Both a colon and semi colon

Comment: Thanks So much for this Wernfried and Bob

Answer (score 2):

What are constraints for?

```
create table t (
  username varchar2(30),
  accountlocked varchar2(1) check( accountlocked in ('Y','N') ),
  constraint not_lock_testuser check( (username,accountlocked) != (('Testuser', 'Y')) )
);
```

Done!

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: But the problem with this is the update fails as and it throws a 500 in the logs and I dont want that...Thanks Tough