# Oracle syncing one table's data with another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables Table 1 and Table 2, both tables have unique id's. Table 1 has Table 2 id as a foreign key.

Table 1

```
id  table2 id
---------------
1    NULL
2    NULL
```

Table 2

```
id     date
---------------
1   '28/12/2019'
2   '30/12/2019'
```

What SQL query to run, every time a new date is added to table 2 date, sync with table 1 data?

Comment: can you provide some more details about this sync process?  Is it as simple as if you add a record in table 2 insert a record in table 1?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to find out here.

Comment: if both the tables are in the same database then you can use insert Trigger.

Comment: The idea that you would want to put the same attribute in two different tables sounds like a design problem.

Comment: @dassum: [using triggers to implement business logic can be a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32009988/213136)

Comment: What is the relationship between `table1.id` and `table2.id`? Is it just a coincidence that they're the same in your posted examples?

Comment: @APC: in the question OP says "Table 1 has Table 2 id as a foreign key."

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - surely that comment refers to the `table1` column named `table2_id`? The question talks about sync'ing the tables which seems to mean inserting a record in `table1`: so where does **its** ID come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following example will help (Oracle 18c).  Ideas: {1} Synchronize the tables with MERGE. {2} Use a procedure for INSERTing into both tables.

**Tables for testing**

```
-- parent (always use DATE for dates!)
create table table2 ( id primary key, date_ )
as 
select 1, to_date( '28/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) from dual union all 
select 2, to_date( '30/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) from dual ;

-- child
create table table1 (
  id number generated always as identity start with 5000 primary key
, table2id number references table2( id ) not null unique
) ;

-- the 2 tables contain the following data:
SQL> select * from table2 ;

        ID DATE_    
---------- ---------
         1 28-DEC-19
         2 30-DEC-19

SQL> select * from table1 ;
no rows selected
```

**{1} MERGE**

```
-- initial sync (P)arent <-> (C)hild
merge into table1 C 
  using table2 P on ( C.table2id = P.id )
when not matched then
  insert ( C.table2id ) values ( P.id ) ;

-- 2 rows merged.

-- data 
SQL> select * from table2 ;

        ID DATE_    
---------- ---------
         1 28-DEC-19
         2 30-DEC-19

SQL> select * from table1 ;

        ID   TABLE2ID
---------- ----------
      5000          1
      5001          2
```

**{2} PROCEDURE**

```
-- assumption: ("parent" table) table2 id generated by a sequence
-- sequence: use nextval and currval.

create sequence t2seq start with 2000 increment by 1 ;

create or replace procedure insert2 ( dt_ date )
is
begin
  insert into table2 ( id, date_ ) values ( t2seq.nextval, dt_ ) ;
  insert into table1 ( table2id ) values ( t2seq.currval ) ;
end ;
/
```

{3} Testing

```
begin
  for i in 100 .. 105
  loop 
    insert2( sysdate + i ) ; -- call the procedure, insert some dates
  end loop;
  commit ;
end ;

-- check: 
SQL> select * from table1 ;

        ID   TABLE2ID
---------- ----------
      5000          1
      5001          2
      5002       2000
      5003       2001
      5004       2002
      5005       2003
      5006       2004
      5007       2005

8 rows selected. 

SQL> select * from table2 ;

        ID DATE_    
---------- ---------
         1 28-DEC-19
         2 30-DEC-19
      2000 07-APR-20
      2001 08-APR-20
      2002 09-APR-20
      2003 10-APR-20
      2004 11-APR-20
      2005 12-APR-20

8 rows selected.
```

{4} Try to sync again -> 0 rows merged.

```
merge into table1 C using table2 P on ( C.table2id = P.id )
when not matched then
  insert ( C.table2id ) values ( P.id ) ;

0 rows merged.
```

[DBfiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=57b07c4be7fc7b73e3e7f8648300108e)
NEXTVAL and CURRVAL documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF50946).

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a record to be inserted into table 1 when a record in table 2 is created, I would recommend adding after insert trigger on table 2.  Here's a link that shows code for such a trigger.  They use the example of an order table with an order audit table to keep track of order changes.

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php

Example trigger from the link above for posterity.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON orders
   FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO orders_audit
   ( order_id,
     quantity,
     cost_per_item,
     total_cost,
     username )
   VALUES
   ( :new.order_id,
     :new.quantity,
     :new.cost_per_item,
     :new.total_cost,
      user );        -- Find username of person performing the INSERT into the table

END;
```

Comment: So with this after insert trigger, how would I exactly structure the code for my problem?

Comment: @mcjoggin - you haven't provided enough details for an exact and complete solution. so either you need to **edit your question** to make it clearer, or you take the principles demonstrated in this answer to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have OneToOne relation between these two tables and you are keeping your audit recored separated from main records. If this is the case:

So one way is to add trigger into the table2.

keep in mind that on the same session you get the same `CURRVAL` of the sequence. and this two tables are sharing the sequence value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_2
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
  :new.ID := TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

  INSERT INTO TABLE_1(ID,TABLE2_ID) VALUES(TABLE_SEQ.CURRVAL,TABLE_SEQ.CURRVAL);

END;
```

you also need to have a sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TABLE_SEQ 
  START WITH 1 
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```